# Is there a way to get Entity Framework tables' IQueryable by Type?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

What I would like to do is:

```
IQueryable<T> getGenericEntityTable<T>(){
  // grab entity table based on context.
  return getIQueryable(m_context, T);
}
```

So I call it like this:

```
IQueryable<MyDBTable_Employee> list = getGenericEntityTable<MyDBTable_Employee>();

list.Where(f => f.employee_name == "Bob");
```

There must be a way to do this in EntityFramework without having to constantly make new files with specific entity calls.

**EDIT:**

**Trying to do this**

```
public IQueryable<T> GetTable<T>(ObjectContext context) where T : class
        {
            var table = context.CreateObjectSet<T>().AsQueryable<T>();
            return table;
        }
```

Comment: this looks good, just remove `AsQueriable<T>()` since `ObjectSet` is already an `IQueryable<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for DbContext API

```
public IQueryable<T> GetTable<T>(DbContext context)
  where T : class
{
  var table = context.Set<T>();
  return table;
}
```

try this for ObjectContext API

```
public IQueryable<T> GetTable<T>(ObjectContext context)
  where T : class
{
  var table = context.CreateObjectSet<T>()
  return table;
}
```

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework. I don't have a "DbContext" whatever that is... I have an ObjectContext.  I'm trying this code: IQueryable<T> table = (IQueryable<T>)context.CreateObjectSet<T>("MyTable");

Comment: See my edit, but this is still giving me errors saying "The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>()'"

Comment: What you did with the generic constraint should be enough, The `Set` method in the DbContext API in EntityFramework calls `CreateObjectSet` internally, so practically is the same thing.
Also, you don't need to call `AsQueryable`, `ObjectSet` is already an `IQueryable<T>`